# Как создать сервер с api

Tags: c#, asp.net, клиент-сервер

Друзья, помогите новичку в немного тупом вопросе.
Вобщем, есть андроид-приложение, и для него нужен сервер с минимальным апи, позволяющим получить в json инфу и записать ее в БД, и соответственно достать ее оттуда и отдать клиенту. Не считая авторизации, 1 пост и 1 гет запрос. Никаких выкрутасов не надо, все минимально просто. Хочу использовать asp.net web api.
Подскажите, есть ли какие нибудь доступные статьи с примером как найти хостинг и залить все это туда.

Comment: php&MySQL не нужны.
Вот ссылка на неплохую краткую документацию на [русском языке](http://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet_webapi/).

Comment: Хороший мануал!

Comment: @Michael это реально очень хороший русский ресурс документации и уроков

Comment: Забрал в закладки! :)

Comment: Смешались в кучу люди, кони. Php - это один язык, с# - это другой язык.

Comment: Лол, да, в голове смешалось. Просто на хостингах для сайтов обычно php msql, а в асп я не знаю)

Comment: Тогда зачем в метки вы asp вписали?

Comment: Ну потому что  хочу попробовать именно асп

Comment: Спасибо, хороший гайд)

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос так, что б после прочтения было понятно на asp вы хотите, на php или и на asp и на php одновременно. А может у вас два вопроса, один про api второй про установку.

Comment: к сожалению, вопросы "какой хостинг выбрать" - оффтопик на SO.

Comment: Переформулировала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит так:

1. Для PHP вам понадобится Apache для ASP.NET понадобится IIS - это полностью разные вещи и как правило хостинги идут сразу с установленным окружением
2. Если вы делаете приложение, которым будут пользоваться люди - бесплатный хостинг это не ваш вариант. Они не надежны и падучи :) Если же пишите апликашку только для теста и для себя, то поставте просто сервер с базой данных и нужное окружение на свой компьютер и все. 
   Для этого есть несколько неплохих решений на просторах интернета. Ищите в гугле по запросу "тестировать серверный api у себя на компьютере". Вот например, что мне показалось вам подойдет: http://getjump.me/ru-php-the-right-way/  Только это для PHP!!

Comment: Приложение будет использоваться, но в узких кругах, свой комп юзать не сильно хочется (если только на начальной стадии). Про падения знаю, но для начала все таки хотим бесплатный. Тогда вопрос такой - на хостинге, как я понимаю, уже стоит бд, но вот как туда залить проект на asp?

Comment: На таких хостингах, как правило, есть ftp по нему и забрасываете. Так же в Visual Studio есть возможность прописать данные для загрузки файлов на север и она сама будет все забрасывать - работа будет удобнее и быстрее.

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Немного прояснилось)